# Use of dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pickup file names from a directory that resides on a specific server. I am using below code:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
 TYPE file_rec IS RECORD (FileName dbms_sql.varchar2_table);
 frec file_rec;

 CURSOR fcur IS
 SELECT fname_krbmsft AS FileName
 FROM x$krbmsft
 WHERE fname_krbmsft LIKE '%.%';

 dirname VARCHAR2(1024) := '\\x.x.x.x\ack';
 ns      VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles(dirname, ns);

  OPEN fcur;
  FETCH fcur BULK COLLECT INTO frec;
  CLOSE fcur;

  FOR i IN 1 .. frec.FileName.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(frec.FileName(i));
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('SUCCESS');

  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('EXCEPTION: '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

On the above script the x.x.x.x is the ip of the server and "ack" is the folder where I want to pickup file names. The problem is that I am not able to pickup these names since x$krbmsft is empty when selected after script exec. Meanwhile if I Replace the server directory with a local directory that resides on my machine (i.e.: C:\test) I am able to pickup file names with this script. I have read access on \x.x.x.x\ack and I am able to enter to this folder from my local PC.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a reason to think Oracle allows that remote path format here? Have you seen it done somewhere else, or have you just assumed that because Windows Explorer allows it then Oracle will? I can't think of anywhere Oracle supports SMB internally.

Comment: Yes, I think SMB is supported. I have done a simple test where I output the content of a file with UTL_FILE.GET_LINE. The file resides on a remote server and its content is output correctly. Then when I use x$krbmsft table I am not able to get filenames if they reside on a remote server. Do you have any additional info to help me?